# SQL XMLNS failing with sp_executesql sproc

Tags: sql, xml-namespaces

I have the following:

```
DECLARE @csXml          XML
      , @changeStatus   XML
      , @tNum           NVARCHAR(25) = '0001aa17'

SELECT @csXml = ChangeSet
  FROM [Issues]
 WHERE [TrackingNumber] = @tNum

SET @changeStatus =
(
    SELECT NEWID()                                      AS [@id]
            , 'me@sample.com'                           AS [@by]
            , '1E910737-D78C-E711-9C04-00090FFE0001'    AS [@byAccountId]
            , '2018-01-18T18:39:03.220Z'                AS [@when]
            , 'Status'      AS [property/@id]
            , 'Status'      AS [property/@name]
            , 'In Review'   AS [property/@old]
            , 'Closed'      AS [property/@new]
            , '' AS [collections]
    FOR XML PATH('change')
);

-- Add node to XML...
SET @csXml.modify(N'declare default element namespace "http://www.sample.com/ChangeSet/2017/09"; 
                         insert sql:variable("@changeStatus") as last into (/changes)[1]');

SET @ParamDef = N'@TrackingNumber NVARCHAR(25)
                , @ChangeSet XML';

SET @sql = 'EXEC [SaveIssue] @TrackingNumber, @ChangeSet';

EXEC [sys].[sp_executesql] @sql
                         , @paramDef
                         , @TrackingNumber = @tNum
                         , @ChangeSet = @csXml;
```

I am getting back an error of:

> Msg 6965, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SaveIssue, Line 27 XML
>   Validation: Invalid content. Expected element(s):
>   '{http://www.sample.com/ChangeSet/2017/09}change'. Found: element
>   'change' instead. Location: /*:changes[1]/*:change[4].

I understand that the sproc I am calling is throwing this error.  What I cannot figure out is how to correctly call this sproc to make it stop!  :)

The (truncated) definition for the sproc is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SaveIssue]
    ( @TrackingNumber NVARCHAR(25)
    , @ChangeSet XML(DOCUMENT Reference.sample) = N'<changes xmlns="http://www.sample.com/ChangeSet/2017/09" />'  
    )
AS
BEGIN
...
END
```

I have tried tying the XMLNS definition to the XML declaration(s), casting the final @csXml to XML and back to XML(DOCUMENT ...), etc.  Nothing I am so far trying is working.  I also tried a `WITH XMLNAMESPACE...` for the @changeStatus SELECT.  I am a bit stumped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CTE solved this for me.  First, I had to change the `SET` to a `SELECT`.  Then added the `WITH XMLNAMESPACE...` portion.  Here is the corrected piece to create the node I want to insert:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.sample.com/ChangeSet/2017/09')
SELECT @changeStatus =
(
    SELECT NEWID()                                      AS [@id]
            , 'me@sample.com'                           AS [@by]
            , '1E910737-D78C-E711-9C04-00090FFE0001'    AS [@byAccountId]
            , '2018-01-18T18:39:03.220Z'                AS [@when]
            , 'Status'      AS [property/@id]
            , 'Status'      AS [property/@name]
            , 'In Review'   AS [property/@old]
            , 'Closed'      AS [property/@new]
            , '' AS [collections]
    FOR XML PATH('change')
);
```